# Bad request on file upload when served from Tomcat but works fine when served from mvn tomcat7:run

Tags: spring-mvc

I have an AngularJS application with a Spring REST api.

The AngularJS static resources can be served by a grunt serve command or by the Apache server or by Tomcat itself.

The api can be served by a manual deploy on a stand alone Tomcat or by the mvn tomcat7:run command.

The version of Tomcat is the 7 one.

All these commands are executed under the very same Linux user.

There is a `Spring` controller file upload handler.

It fails when served from a grunt serve + Tomcat and it fails when served from a grunt build + Tomcat and it fails when served from Apache + Tomcat

It works fine when served from grunt serve + mvn tomcat7:run , and works fine when served from grunt serve:dist + mvn tomcat7:run and works fine when served from apache + mvn tomcat7:run

All above commands are done on my development server.

It also fails in the same fashion on the Tomcat of the production server.

I understand the grunt build is doing its job then.

The error is the same in Chromium and in Firefox.

Removing the method = RequestMethod.POST annotation from the controller handler did not change anything in the console error output.

The issue should rest with the server side... The error message is: Request method 'POST' not supported

The failing request as seen in the Chromium browser:

```
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:8080
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/nitro-manager-rest/api/rollouts/import
Request Method:POST
Status Code:400 Bad Request
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,fr;q=0.6,es;q=0.4,et;q=0.2,nb;q=0.2,ru;q=0.2,sv;q=0.2,it;q=0.2,de;q=0.2
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:2389
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarykinGH3Nf0BBnRvRW
Host:localhost:8080
Origin:http://localhost:9000
Referer:http://localhost:9000/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/34.0.1847.116 Chrome/34.0.1847.116 Safari/537.36
X-Auth-Token:eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJleHAiOjE0MTc4NjY2NjAsInN1YiI6Im5zbkBuc24uY29tIn0.OhfS2HFFjXC64Ql7h6--PkrUvFbBis8CiFPb4HGn1_k
Request Payload
------WebKitFormBoundarykinGH3Nf0BBnRvRW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="SFR-rollout-rollout-export.zip"
Content-Type: application/zip


------WebKitFormBoundarykinGH3Nf0BBnRvRW--
Response Headersview source
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Accept-Language,Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers,Authorization,X-Filename,Content-Disposition,Content-Length,X-Auth-Token
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:9000
Access-Control-Expose-Headers:Accept-Language,Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers,Authorization,X-Filename,Content-Disposition,Content-Length,X-Auth-Token
Access-Control-Max-Age:3600
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Connection:close
Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date:Mon, 01 Dec 2014 15:41:04 GMT
Expires:0
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:DENY
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block
```

The successful request as seen in the Chromium browser:

```
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:8080
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/nitro-manager-rest/api/rollouts/import
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,fr;q=0.6,es;q=0.4,et;q=0.2,nb;q=0.2,ru;q=0.2,sv;q=0.2,it;q=0.2,de;q=0.2
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:2389
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryJHnXN3HjJJNYTURZ
Host:localhost:8080
Origin:http://localhost:9000
Referer:http://localhost:9000/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/34.0.1847.116 Chrome/34.0.1847.116 Safari/537.36
X-Auth-Token:eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJleHAiOjE0MTc4NjY2NjAsInN1YiI6Im5zbkBuc24uY29tIn0.OhfS2HFFjXC64Ql7h6--PkrUvFbBis8CiFPb4HGn1_k
Request Payload
------WebKitFormBoundaryJHnXN3HjJJNYTURZ
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="SFR-rollout-rollout-export.zip"
Content-Type: application/zip


------WebKitFormBoundaryJHnXN3HjJJNYTURZ--
Response Headersview source
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Accept-Language,Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers,Authorization,X-Filename,Content-Disposition,Content-Length,X-Auth-Token
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:9000
Access-Control-Expose-Headers:Accept-Language,Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers,Authorization,X-Filename,Content-Disposition,Content-Length,X-Auth-Token
Access-Control-Max-Age:3600
Cache-Control:no-store
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date:Sun, 30 Nov 2014 21:51:40 GMT
Expires:Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Location:http://localhost:8080/nitro-manager-rest/api/rollouts/import?file=[org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile@2a52c0]
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:DENY
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block
```

The controller handler:

```
@ProductManager
@Controller
@RequestMapping(RESTConstants.SLASH + RESTConstants.ROLLOUTS)
public class RolloutImportController {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RolloutImportController.class);

    @Autowired 
    private ResourceService resourceService;

    @Autowired 
    private RolloutService rolloutService;

    @Autowired 
    private ExportService exportService;

    @Autowired
    private RolloutResourceAssembler rolloutResourceAssembler;

    @RequestMapping(value = RESTConstants.SLASH + RESTConstants.SLASH + RESTConstants.IMPORT, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<List<String>> rolloutImport(@RequestParam(value = "file") List<MultipartFile> files, UriComponentsBuilder builder) {
        logger.debug("==========>> In rolloutImport");
        HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        List<String> messages = exportService.rolloutImport(files);
        responseHeaders.setLocation(builder.path(RESTConstants.SLASH + RESTConstants.ROLLOUTS + RESTConstants.SLASH + RESTConstants.IMPORT).queryParam("file", files).buildAndExpand().toUri());
        return new ResponseEntity<List<String>>(messages, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

On my development server the log says:

```
2014-11-30 17:08:29,967 DEBUG  [DispatcherServlet] DispatcherServlet with name 'NITRo' processing POST request for [/nitro-manager-rest/api/rollouts/import] 
2014-11-30 17:08:30,145 DEBUG  [CommonsMultipartResolver] Found multipart file [file] of size 2194 bytes with original filename [Orange-rollout-rollout-export.zip], stored in memory 
2014-11-30 17:08:30,151 DEBUG  [RequestMappingHandlerMapping] Looking up handler method for path /rollouts/import 
2014-11-30 17:08:30,180 DEBUG  [RequestMappingHandlerMapping] Returning handler method [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.List<java.lang.String>> com.nsn.nitro.project.rest.controller.RolloutImportController.rolloutImport(java.util.List<org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile>,org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder)]
```

But on my production server it says:

```
2014-11-30 17:26:35,839 DEBUG  [RequestMappingHandlerMapping] Looking up handler method for path /rollouts/import 
2014-11-30 17:26:35,858 DEBUG  [ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver] Resolving exception from handler [null]: org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported
```

EDIT: I added logback-access output and the console log has this to show:

```
POST /nitro-manager-rest/api/rollouts/import HTTP/1.1
host: localhost:8080
connection: keep-alive
content-length: 2389
origin: http://localhost:9000
x-auth-token: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJleHAiOjE0MTc4NjY2NjAsInN1YiI6Im5zbkBuc24uY29tIn0.OhfS2HFFjXC64Ql7h6--PkrUvFbBis8CiFPb4HGn1_k
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/34.0.1847.116 Chrome/34.0.1847.116 Safari/537.36
content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryEDbGOJFhgA4Olleb
accept: */*
referer: http://localhost:9000/
accept-encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.8,fr;q=0.6,es;q=0.4,et;q=0.2,nb;q=0.2,ru;q=0.2,sv;q=0.2,it;q=0.2,de;q=0.2    

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Accept-Language,Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers,Authorization,X-Filename,Content-Disposition,Content-Length,X-Auth-Token
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Expires: 0
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE
Connection: close
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Accept-Language,Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers,Authorization,X-Filename,Content-Disposition,Content-Length,X-Auth-Token
Date: Mon, 01 Dec 2014 14:37:18 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:9000
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
```

EDIT: The issue comes from the controller class where the handler sits in. Moving the handler into another controller class solves the issue. Changing the mapping value attribute of the controller class does not solve the issue. I hope to solve this soon.

EDIT: I could find a work around the issue. This is not a solution. Just a work around. By moving the handler:

```
@RequestMapping(value = RESTConstants.SLASH + RESTConstants.IMPORT, method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<List<String>> rolloutImport(@RequestParam(value = "file") List<MultipartFile> files, UriComponentsBuilder builder) {
    HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    List<String> messages = exportService.rolloutImport(files);
    responseHeaders.setLocation(builder.path(RESTConstants.SLASH + RESTConstants.ROLLOUTS + RESTConstants.SLASH + RESTConstants.IMPORT).queryParam("file", files).buildAndExpand().toUri());
    return new ResponseEntity<List<String>>(messages, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

outside of the controller class:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(RESTConstants.SLASH + RESTConstants.ROLLOUTS)
public class RolloutImportController {
```

into any other controller class, like into the controller class:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(RESTConstants.SLASH + RESTConstants.ROLLOUTS)
public class RolloutExportController {
```

made it work perfectly fine.

I have no idea why.

I suspected the two controller classes having the same mapping:

```
@RequestMapping(RESTConstants.SLASH + RESTConstants.ROLLOUTS)
```

could be trouble and renamed one of them but it didn't change anything to the issue.

I then suspected the "import" word in the handler mapping to be part of the issue, like, it being mapped in some Spring Security configuration or something else (a source code search returned nothing with "import" anyway), and so I also changed the mapping of the handler itself from:

```
@RequestMapping(value = RESTConstants.SLASH + RESTConstants.IMPORT, method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

to:

```
@RequestMapping(value = RESTConstants.SLASH + "myimp", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

but it also did not change anything to the issue.

For now, I'm happy with my work around, but I'm still bewildered by the issue.